# Django - making child class inherit overloaded save method of its parent abstract class

Tags: django

I am newbie in Django and notably its inheritance tools. 
I have the following architecture:

```
   class BaseMixin(models.Model):
       effective_from = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

       class Meta:
           abstract = True 
   class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
       def get_queryset(self):
          # ...
       def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
            return getattr(self.get_queryset(), attr, *args)
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # I want this method to be deployed for my_model_instance.save()

    class MyModel(BaseMixin):
       # ...
       objects = QuerySetManager()

       class Meta:
           managed = False
           db_table = 'my_model'

       class QuerySet(QuerySet):
           # ...
```

So my goal is to call `QuerySetManager`'s `save` method when trying to save changes to my_model_instance. The question is, should I overload `save` method in `BaseMixin` ? Or in `QuerySetManager` ? I tied both, and as for now, Django ignores my custom save method in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BaseMixin is abstract class which you are inheriting at other places.

ModelManagers doesn't provide a save method , it's meant for abstracting out complex logic while querying a particular model.

You need to override save MyModel here. Something like.

```
class MyModel(BaseMixin):
    # ...
    objects = QuerySetManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_model'


    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
        print "In Save Method"
        return super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Save method is property of model instance.

Simple Example.

```
def my_view(request,pk):
    my_model = MyModel.object.get(id=pk)
    my_model.field_1 = "new value"
    ## When you call save method your custom save method is called first.
    my_model.save()
```

Comment: Bipul, didn't understand your response in all honesty. And what is the syntax of calling the save method with such approach ?

Comment: Is `def save` just a simple view ?

Comment: Sorry def save was indentation issue :) added more example.

Comment: Simply it's a bit repetitive. I mean, I have to define the same save method for all children of `BaseMixin`. And this method is absolutely the same. I have separated the code into a view and then I write `def save(self,...) { standard_save_method(self, ....)}. Well, I've minimized the repetition, but still it's a bit irritating that I have to add this bunch of lines for each and every non-abstract class throughout the entire project